# Cannot find ActiveRecord Class in Rails 6 with Phobos Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-kafka

I am using the [phobos gem](https://github.com/phobos/phobos) to consume Kakfa Messages in a Rails App and I have it configured within the rails `config/initializers/phobos.rb` to start an `executor` from the `config/phobos.yml` like the the following:

`config/initializers/phobos.rb`:

```
Phobos.configure('config/phobos.yml')
executor = Phobos::Executor.new
executor.start
```

I get a  `:exception_class=>"NameError", :exception_message=>"uninitialized constant TransactionsConsumer::Address"` error when trying to load the `Address` model from `ActiveRecord`. There should be no `TransactionsConsumer::Address` but it should find the `Address` class in `app/models/address.rb`.

My Consumer in `app/consumers/transactions_consumer.rb`:

```
class TransactionsConsumer
  include Phobos::Handler

  def self.start(kafka_client)
    # setup handler
    puts "Starting Transaction Consumer"
  end

  def consume(payload, metadata)
    puts metadata
    puts payload
    data = JSON.parse(payload)
    if Address.exists?(address: data["fromAddress"])
      AccountBalanceUpdateJob.perform_in(1, data["fromAddress"])
    end
  end
end
```

I assume I'm not configuring Phobos correctly in some way to autoload or see the Rails Classes. How do I get Phobos configured to work with Rails models/objects?

Does the `TransactionConsumer` class need to `include` or `require` something special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was my own fault. I had renamed the `Address` class to `Account` and I thought it was because of the way I was starting `rails` and `phobos`

Changing:

```
if Address.exists?(address: data["fromAddress"])
  AccountBalanceUpdateJob.perform_in(1, data["fromAddress"])
end
```

To:

```
if Account.exists?(address: data["fromAddress"])
  AccountBalanceUpdateJob.perform_in(1, data["fromAddress"])
end
```

Fixed the issue.